# Does Ubuntu deliberately slow down the system when updates are available, until applied?

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu

This might sound like a stupid question but I have some odd behavior with my Ubuntu 19.04 server which runs Squid proxy. When updates are available I notice the system and net traffic that runs through the proxy slows down. It's not a huge reduction, but there is a reduction and it's enough to be noticeable.

This has been occurring on my network for a couple of weeks and at first I didn't know which server was causing it. My Squid proxy is what I have narrowed it down to. Once the updates have been applied, the system and net traffic runs through the proxy at normal speed again.

I'm not aware of any Linux system performing this kind of stupid behavior. I'd expect it from Microsoft, but not from Linux. So I ask the legitimate question:

Does Ubuntu deliberately slow systems and/or network traffic until updates have been applied?

Comment: No, it doesn't.

Comment: IMHO better rephrase the question as "What could slow down Ubuntu when updates are available"? And provide evidence of the slow down (what is measured, how it is measured, and the hard results).

Comment: Guess: The updates are being downloaded in the background as an "optimization".

Comment: @harrymc The slowdown would cease once the updates are downloaded, but here this happens when they are applied.

Comment: @xenoid: Installing might just finish the download quicker in the foreground.

Comment: @Harrymc Current pending updates for my server (updates for kernel, glib, apache, php, mySQL, python 2 & 3 and other small stuff) total 60MB. This is small by today's standard, unless the OP has a very slow link...

Comment: I haven't got numbers and data to justify my question because I know when my server is normal and when it's slow. I don't need to go mapping data and other useless analytics to tell me that. If I was to do that I wouldn't be asking the question in the first place because I would know where the problem lies. The updates are not downloaded in the background until I manually prompt them to download.